# Website domain redirects to IP and asks for network registration

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-cloud-platform, a-records

When going to my website:

[www.d3.digital](http://www.d3.digital)

it redirects to the ip and asks for users to register.

My A record points to the IP shown in the domain.  But the domain doesn't show up in the address bar?

Does anyone know whats happening? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't change the text of the link to appear as something else - it's misleading and against site rules.

Answer (score 1):

The web server at the IP address associated with `www.d3.digital` (`104.154.217.111`) responds with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 10:35:26 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.15
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://104.154.217.111/wp-signup.php?new=www.d3.digital
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Which is indeed a redirect to a URL with an IP address rather than a domain name in it. It does, however, have absolutely nothing to do with DNS and everything to do with how your web server is configured.

Answer (score 1):

The redirected url (http://104.154.217.111/wp-signup.php?new=www.d3.digital) listed in the Location header suggests that your website is based on Wordpresss.

Its possible that your Wordpress installation does not have the correct site name configured. Or one of your Wordpress plugins is not working correctly